# Segregate multi-line transactions based on row values

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a retail transaction data set that looks like:

```
TRANSID GROSS AMNT  TRANSROWTYPE  
123         50          Z  
123         20          A  
123         30          A  
126         90          Z  
126         20          A  
126         30          A  
126         20          A  
…           ..          .
```

Where,
•   `TRANDIS` is a transaction identifier
•   `GROSS AMNT` is the gross amount for the transaction row
•   `TRANSROWTYPE` is the row type for a transaction.

All transactions have 2 types of Rows

1. Type `A`: Detailed row(s) of the transaction. A transaction can have 1 or multiple Type `A` rows.
2. Type `Z`: Header row for the transaction. A transaction can have only 1 Type `Z` row.

Ideally for a `TRANSID`, the sum of `GROSS AMNT`s in Type `A` rows should equal the `GROSS AMNT` in a Type `Z` row.

In the sample, this is true for `TRANSID=123`, but not for `TRANSID=126`.

My query is how do I segregate the `TRANSIDs` that have
`GROSS AMNTs` in Type `A` rows= `GROSS AMNT`s in Type `Z` row from those where the two are not equal?

I am particularly interested to  find a solution using `dplyr`

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in a single shot with dplyr. First you summarise in order to condense multiple rows of same type. It will only affect A type rows, since Z rows only happen once anyway for each transation id.

Right after summarising you do a pivot_wider() so the values for A and Z can be side by side on the same row, making it very easy to compare and filter only those that suit your criteria.

```
retail %>%
  group_by(TRANSID, TRANSROWTYPE) %>%
  summarise(TOTAL.AMT = sum(`GROSS AMNT`)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "TRANSROWTYPE", values_from = "TOTAL.AMT") %>%
  subset(A != Z)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of getting the desired result using the `tidyverse` package, so here is just another option.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  #Group by TRANS and TRANSROWTYPE
  group_by(TRANSID, TRANSROWTYPE) %>%
  #Get the sum of GROSS AMT by ID and row type
  summarise(sum_amt = sum(`GROSS AMNT`)) %>%
  #Ungroup
  ungroup() %>%
  #Group by ID
  group_by(TRANSID) %>%
  #Get distinct values
  distinct(sum_amt) %>%
  #Remove rows where sum_amt is the same for A and Z per ID (i.e., n = 1)
  #and stay only with rows where there are 2 distinct values
  filter(n() >= 2)
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, The solution works. Also, appreciate the comments to help explain.